# How to read Values from TYPE in Oracle for the Collection (Map) type

Tags: java, sql, oracle

In oracle i have created

```
create type INTERFACE_VALUES as OBJECT (
IVKEY VARCHAR2(32),
IVVALUE VARCHAR2(250)
```

);

and

```
create type T_INTERFACE_VALUES as TABLE OF INTERFACE_VALUES;
```

and from java side i am passing one MAP as input to Stored procedure by converting map into Array.

and i have created one One Stored Procedure for accepting this map as input parameter.

> ```
> PROCEDURE S_MAP_PARAMETERS(   pVALUES IN T_INTERFACE_VALUES   ) AS
>  ???
> ```
>
> END S_MAP_PARAMETERS;

so i need to read pVALUES in SQL how do i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested table types in Oracle are not key-value collections. So you need to loop through the table `pValues` then for each object you can access the attributes `IVVALUE` and `IVKEY`, you can do that in multiple ways:

1- via a cursor using the `TABLE` function

```
CURSOR iterate as
SELECT *
  FROM TABLE(pValues)
```

Then in your code

```
For Rec in iterate
loop
    --for example
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec.IVVALUE)
end loop;
```

2- looping one item at a time, using the nested tables `count` function:

```
For indx in 1..pValues.COUNT
Loop
 --access it using indx pvalues(indx)
 --for example
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(pvalues(indx).IVVALUE)

end loop
```

Comment: can you please provide me any LOOP code for last Block..i tried like
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Parameters ' ||pValues(index) );

and it has compilation errors..

Comment: `pValues(index)` will give u access to an Object/Type instance so you need to use the attribute name to get the value. In your case that would be either `IVVALUE` or 'IVKEY', I will edit my answer to show that

Comment: I just did, if u r new to SQL. Then let me ask you something, did you do the mapping between your Java type and `T_INTERFACE_VALUES` nested table type?

Comment: yes i did it and it worked i am able to get my MAP values in SQL...
Thanks Jafar..

Answer (score 1):

In SQL

```
SELECT ivkey, ivvalue
  FROM TABLE( pValues );
```

would work.  If you really mean to ask how to access the collection in PL/SQL, assuming the collection is dense.

```
FOR i IN 1..pValues.count
LOOP
  dbms_output.put_line( 'Key = ' || pValues(i).ivkey ||
                        ' Value = ' || pValues(i).ivvalue );
END LOOP;
```

If you expect some elements of the collection to be missing (which seems odd given your choice of PL/SQL collection), the loop gets a bit more complicated since you've got to call `FIRST` and `NEXT` to iterate through the elements.

If you want to create a PL/SQL construct that is more similar to your Map in Java, you'd want something like

```
CREATE TYPE map_t
  AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(250)
      INDEX BY VARCHAR2(32)
```